# Debug Dart within Office 365 App Part

Tags: dart, sharepoint-2013

I have created a nodeJS application that code-generates a Dartlang  INTEROP package from the SP API TypeScript definition file for Office 365, SharePoint Online.

I am attempting to utilize Visual Studio 2013 (update 4) to deploy a test App part into SharePoint online, where the app.js will be the main function from a dart test application, code would look something like the following ...

```js
import 'package:ms_sp_api/js_api_sp.dart' as SP;
void main() {
  SP.ClientContext clientContext;
  SP.ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo;
  SP.Web web;
  var list;

  clientContext =  new SP.ClientContext("url to test site")..get_current();
  //sp..get_current();
  web = clientContext.get_web();
  listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
  listCreationInfo.set_title("User data");
  listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
  list = web.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);

  clientContext.load(list);
}
```

Assuming I am able to deploy the Dart file(s) as a SharePoint App part, and assuming I am able to get the App part to call the main() function of the test Dart application, I still need to be able to debug the Dart file.
Would I be able to attach Dartium to the URL of the deployed App Part and successfully debug it?

My hope is that after I have it debugged, the I would dart2js the dart app and that would be the script that gets deployed in the App part.  I have successfully deployed simple dart applications within app parts but in this case I need to debug the app part in order to get the SP API for Dart working.  I don't believe I can test the code-generated API locally, it must be hosted within a SharePoint app part/page.

Here is a high level overview of what I am attempting to create which is a series of Business components that are built entirely within Dart that can be deployed into O365 and leverage a number of 3rd party JS libraries that I am very close to having through a set of Typescript to Dart, code-generated Dart JS INTEROP libraries ...

[image]

Any ideas or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the page in Dartium, open Chrome dev tools, find the script in the `sources` tab, set a breakpoint and do something that invokes the code. Then the breakpoint should be hit.

Comment: Thanks! Can you confirm this is what I would deploy to the O365 App Part within Visual Studio  ... I was planning on including all dart files derived from the dart application including the dart file containing main() function, as well the dart project's html with script references to the SP API JS scripts within the target web site. I will also deploy all content within the packages folder from the test dart application which will include all dart source files including the SP API INTEROP libraries dart files and any other imported dart package's dart files. Is that seem about right?

Comment: For debugging purposes or really "deploy"? For real deployment you need to run `pub build` to generate JavaScript and then deploy the files form `build/web`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Günter, the approach does work, but only within a Provider Hosted App Model and not SharePoint Hosted App model.  The reason is that currently SharePoint Online does not allow you to specify additional MIME Types, thus `application/dart` is rejected.  In a Provider Hosted model you can deploy as an MVC project that is hosted in a separate server (Azure in my case) and then you simply add a new MIMETYPE to IISExpress.

I also recommend downloading the Web Essentials VISX extension for Visual Studio which allows you to establish the target browser as Chromium (found in dart).

The other thing I did was I created the Dart project underneath/within the MVC folder so that it can be included directly into the MVC project.  This will allow me to include several Dart projects within the single app part project as I need to test a lot of the code generated API proxy.

I use Web Storm to edit the Dart projects and then need only add a light be of integration logic within the MVC project to pull the dart logic directly into the MVC project.  Having the dart project directly within Visual Studio MVC project has the added benefit of having all dart files being managed within TFS, in sync within the SharePoint App part project.

The following is a high-level overview of the transformation from Typescript definition files to Dart INTEROP proxy library. I use the Abstract Syntax Tree node service that is integrated within Typescript to dissect the Typescript Definition file. It is an iterative process in which I re-run the transformer adding additional insight into the transformation processor (via the XML helper file) for things such as renaming type names, class singleton, underlying enum types and constructor/class body definitions. The transformer is pretty decent but needs a little help to generate the correct output. My hope is to be able to transform any Typescript definition file in order to code-generate an equivalent Dart API proxy library which should make integrating with 3rd party JS libraries a breeze (assuming the Typescript Definition file is of quality).

[image]

Now that I know this MVC integrated approach actually works it will allow me to debug the code-generated SharePoint/Office 365 API INTEROP proxy library for dart which is actually quite massive in size and complexity and as such I am ever so grateful to be able to step through it, within Chromium debugger.

Once I have completed all testing I will build the final product to JS script which will be  directly included within a production ready SP Web part and at which point could be either SharePoint hosted or Provided Hosted as at that point it's just JavaScript (the true benefit of Dart).

Thanks again for your help.

Cheers
John

Comment: You need the `Provider Hosted App Model` during debugging?

Comment: Yep, I couldn't get the SP hosted App Model to debug due to MIME Type concerns.